# Existence of a function with a changing period

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> $f,\alpha$ are continuous $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ functions satisfying:
>
> $$f\big(x+\alpha(x)\big)=f(x)$$
>
> If $f$ is non-constant, must $\alpha$ be constant?

My idea was to use the fact that no real function can have a double period, but I don't know how to apply it, or whether this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the first example that comes to mind:
$$
f(x) = \sin(x^2)
$$
In this case, we can take 
$$
\alpha(x) = \sqrt{x^2+2\pi}-x
$$
which is continuous but not constant.

---

For a somewhat more remarkable example, the function
$$
f(x) = \cos(x+\frac{1}{100}\sin(x))
$$
Is periodic in both your sense and in the sense of a constant period, since we may select an $\alpha(x)$ that is itself periodic.  The analysis of such functions is important for applications such as [FM radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation).